# Script to access all the existing homes

Tags: scripts

I'm new to bash scripting and I'm trying to create a script which goes trough all the userhomes for several machines to delete entries from the authorized_keys.
Deleting the entries is easy, but to remove it from all the existing homes, I have to access the machine, get the homes and create a list, or do it one by one.
I would like to do it dynamically.

Conditions

- Those machines may not have the same users, but it should not be a problem.
- I can't use an static list, because the users may change (new users, users deleted).
- Some users are local, and some are NFS mounted under /home.
- I have to remove the public key of a given user, from some of those homes. The user public key, could be in all or just a few homes, that's why I need to run the script in all the existing homes. I want to avoid the user from ssh to a local user in this machine using his public key.

The only "solution" I can think of, is to create a list from the passwd for the local homes and then, add to the list the NFS users from the fstab, but it seems to be quite complex for such a task.

Is there an easier way to run a script for all the existing $home in a machine?

To remove the entry I use sed, and this is tested and working. The script works perfectly when I manually define the home from which I want to remove the entry.

Thanks.

EDIT:
OK. A huge mistake. I'm talking about the authorized_keys. I don't know why I wrote know_hosts

Comment: In my case I get the key I want to remove from another script, and remove the entry with sed. This part is tested and working.
You are right, I was not clear enough. I'll edit my question
I need to remove public keys for certain users from several homes.

Comment: Yes sorry. I don't why I wrote know_hosts. This is from another script I was working on, so I guess my mind betrayed me. I realized it later. I need to remove the entry from the authorized_keys. I'm going crazy hahaha

Comment: See if my answer works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
   
for user in $(getent passwd | cut -f1 -d: );
    if [[ -f "$user/.ssh/authorized_keys" ]]; then
        ... your sed command ...
done

users=(/nfsshares/*)    
for user in "${users[@]}"; do
if [[ -f "$user/.ssh/authorized_keys" ]]; then
    ... your sed command ...
fi
done
```

Comment: But this won't get the NFS homes. That's why I was thinking of dynamically create a list from both, the passwd and the fstab. But I don't like this approach.

Comment: Ok. I think this will work. I listed all the users and I realized the NFS account I was using as reference is wrong. So we have fixed two things hahaha. A profile which was not being mounted properly and the method to do it.
I've lost the whole morning with this script. Next time I'll take more than one value as reference.

Comment: oh but you could do this TWICE. This current one for normal users and then a 2nd for NFS shares.  See the edit. That would run through /nfshares/ and check for /nsfshares/*/.ssh/authorized_keys Sooooooooooo many options ;-)

Comment: Yes, this will work. It still leaves some traces from the manual added comments, but that's not the point.
Thank you :)

Comment: think you are missing the base */home/$user*.... but think its probably better to traverse the /home dir directly.